# "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items" Themes & SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, themes

So I have this website that will be accessed via an SSL connection ("https://mystupidwebsite/etc...")

I am using themes in conjunction with a single css file. when the page is rendered though, the CSS link tag in the header still has the http://mystupidwebsite/etc... full path.

How do I get it to regester the css file correctly, with the https or use relative paths?

thanks,

Nate

Edit: Oh! I just found my issue. Themes are correctly adding the css with a relative path. There was a link tag in the master page that was using absolute paths to the same css. sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I assume you have the css file statically linked via a link tag rather than just dumping it in the theme folder?

Comment: i just have the css dumped in the theme folder. is that bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link to `/path/to/style.css` instead of with the full `http://example.com/path/to/style.css`. This assumes you've got the same content being served to HTTPS and HTTP requests. If not, you'll need to make an alias or symbolic link or something.

Comment: I just have the css file dumped in the theme folder, and i am letting the Theme automatically add the link tag

Answer (score 3):

use relative pathing

Comment: i really want to, BUT the link tag in the header is automatically generated by the theme

Comment: you can add additional link headers, as well as just adding the css in the theme, are you saying the theme is not coming over relative?

Comment: the theme is not adding the link to the css as a relative path. :( Its adding it with the absolute url that is not secured. is there a property or something on themes to only use relative paths?